# ValueError: name is not a valid ExplainerComponent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to visualize my dashboards in the ExplainerHub. However, my comparison tab runs when I run it alone, but not in ExplainerHub. As a result, I am getting this ValueError: name is not a valid ExplainerComponent...
Here is the dashboard I am trying to run as a comparison dashboard:

````
class ResultComparison(ExplainerComponent):
    def __init__(self, explainer_lgbm, explainer_xgb):
        super().__init__(explainer_catb)
                
        # ShapDependenceComponent
        self.confmat_catb_shap_dep = ShapDependenceComponent(explainer_catb, subtitle='CatBoost', cutoff=0.3,
                            hide_selector=True, hide_percentage=True)
        self.confmat_xgb_shap_dep = ShapDependenceComponent(explainer_xgb, subtitle='XGBoost', cutoff=0.3,
                            hide_selector=True, hide_percentage=True)
        
        # PrecisionComponent
        self.confmat_catb_prec = PrecisionComponent(explainer_catb, subtitle='CatBoost', cutoff=0.3,
                            hide_selector=True, hide_percentage=True)
        self.confmat_xgb_prec = PrecisionComponent(explainer_xgb, subtitle='XGBoost', cutoff=0.3,
                            hide_selector=True, hide_percentage=True)
       
    def layout(self):
        return dbc.Container([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    self.confmat_catb_shap_dep.layout()
                ]),
                dbc.Col([
                    self.confmat_xgb_shap_dep.layout()
                ]),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    self.confmat_catb_prec.layout()
                ]),
                dbc.Col([
                    self.confmat_xgb_prec.layout()
                ]),

            ]),
        ])
    
tab = ResultComparison(explainer_catb, explainer_xgb)

db_comp = ExplainerDashboard(explainer_xgb, tabs=tab, name='comparison', title="Comarison Results",
                            decision_trees=False,
                            whatif=False,
                            shap_interaction=False,
                            contributions=False, 
                             model_summary=False, 
                             shap_dependence=False)
# run comparison dashboard alone
#db_comp.run(8052)
# Run all dashboards in a single host
#db_catb, db_lgbm, db_xgb, 
hub = ExplainerHub([db_comp])
hub.run(8053)```


When I run explainer it throws this error.
````

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it comes from this line:

```py
# your way
db_comp = ExplainerDashboard(explainer_xgb, tabs=tab, ...)

# correct way
db_comp = ExplainerDashboard(explainer_xgb, tabs=[tab], ...)
```

The line that throws the error is called by this line:

```py
self.tabs  = [
   instantiate_component(tab, explainer, name=str(i+1), **kwargs)
   for i, tab in enumerate(tabs)
]
```

Apparently it does not accept `tab` but it should accept `[tab]`, as it should be a list of components.
The thrown error is not very explanatory, and in the documentation it is used in both `tab` and `[tab]` forms, but only `[tab]` is correct.

Possibly when it is doing the iteration (as it expects a list to enumerate) it is actually iterating this tuple `(tab, explainer, name=str(i+1), **kwargs)`, so it gets the parameter 'name', and it is actually throwing that: `ValueError: name is not a valid ExplainerComponent`, as name is not a component, correctly.